# How can i get space using fscanf from a file with delimiters between data

Tags: c, file, delimiter, scanf

I have a text file with the information bellow. Each record have 200Bytes in size, but it generally use less than this 200B, as you can see there are some spaces after each record to make it 200B. My problem is that i need to solve this problem with very low numbers of seek and read the most information I can get. So I want to read this file using something like below:

```
char auxStr[50];
fscanf(f,"%[^\n]s|",auxStr); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM, IT DOES NOT WORK
p->nome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(auxStr)+1);
strcpy(p->nome,auxStr);
printf(" %s\n\n", p->nome);
```

I want that *auxStr* have this value with whitespace *"St Charles,961"*, is it possible to do it using some c function like fscanf or will i have to use a loop and read every character until i found the delimeter '|'?

Ps: Using a loop will solve the problem but i believe it will use the most number of seeks that's possible. I think i can not use fgets cause i don't know the length of the string to be read.

Text File:

```
85 82|AAAA|BBBB|St Charles,961|Sao Carlos|Sao Paulo|13560-0520|-1|-------------------------
|8585|FFFFFF|RRR| RUA Y, 888|Rio de janeiro|585996-988|-1|---------------------------------
|98 85|ZZZZ|YYYY|AV YYY,889|SP|949845-45354|-23|-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion to read all the field from one line.

```
char field1[50];
char field2[50];
char field3[50];
char field4[50];
char field5[50];
char field6[50];
char field7[50];
char field8[50];

fscanf(f, "%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%[^|]s|%[^|]s|",
          field1, field2, field3, field4,
          field5, field6, field7, field8);
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the fields happen to be blank. Indeed, the OP's sample data file, the first field in the 2nd and 3rd lines is blank (although this is likely garbled).